# argparse subparsers inheriting options from top level parser

Tags: python, inheritance, argparse

I'm sure this has answers somewhere but I'm either not employing the threads I've found correctly, or I'm not hitting the right keywords.

I'm experimenting with a python script for which I'm trying to write 3 subcommands, so I'm using the subparser syntax of `argparse`, but I've not used subparsers before and I've exhausted everything in the `argparse` docs that seems relevant to subcommands. I'm getting there, the commands all register correctly, however, I specifically want the 1 required argument that's passed to the top level parser to be available to all the subparsers (each subcommand will act upon the same input file).

It's a big script, but here's the argparse part.

```
def parseArgs():
    """Parse command line arguments. Includes parsing of subcommands."""

    import argparse

    try:
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='MSAnalysis',
                                         description="Perform simple tasks with multiple sequence alignments. \n The following subcommands are available:")
        subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(title='Subcommands')
        parser_consensus = subparsers.add_parser('consensus',
                                                 description='Calculate a \'dumb\' consensus via BioPython.',
                                                 help='Computer a consensus sequence from the MSA, at a specifiable threshold.')
        parser_entropy   = subparsers.add_parser('entropy',
                                                 description='Perform calculation of the Shannon entropy per column of an MSA.',
                                                 help='Compute the Shannon entropy, per column of the MSA and return 2 vectors.')
        parser_selection = subparsers.add_parser('selection',
                                                 description='Selection pressure Calculator',
                                                 help='Report dN/dS ratio in either a sliding window or for a whole sequence.')

        # Main parser required options
        parser.add_argument('-a',
                            '--alignment',
                            action='store',
                            required=True,
                            help='The multiple sequence alignment (MSA) in any of the formats supported by Biopython\'s AlignIO.')
        # Main parser options
        parser.add_argument('-f',
                            '--alnformat',
                            action='store',
                            default='fasta',
                            help='Specify the format of the input MSA to be passed in to AlignIO. [Default = fasta].')
        parser.add_argument('-v',
                            '--verbose',
                            action='count',
                            default=1,
                            help='Verbose behaviour, printing parameters of the script and status messages.')
        parser.add_argument('--makeplot',
                            action='store_true',
                            help='Plot the results via Matplotlib.')

        # parser_entropy
        parser_entropy.add_argument('-m',
                                    '--runningmean',
                                    action='store',
                                    type=int,
                                    default=0,
                                    help='Return the running mean (a.k.a moving average) of the MSAs Shannon Entropy. Makes for slightly smoother plots. Providing the number of points to average over switches this on.')

        # parser_consensus
        parser_consensus.add_argument('-c',
                                      '--ambiguous',
                                      action='store',
                                      help='Specify what character default to use for ambiguous characters within alignments.')
        parser_consensus.add_argument('-t',
                                      '--threshold',
                                      action='store',
                                      help='Threshold cut off for the consensus sequence calculation.')

        # parser_dnds options
        parser_selection.add_argument('-p',
                                      '--phylogeny',
                                      action='store',
                                      help='Specify a tree file computed from the supplied alignment for use with PAML.')

    except:
        print "An exception occurred with argument parsing. Check your provided options."
        traceback.print_exc()

    return parser.parse_args()
```

I'd like `consensus`, `entropy`, and `selection` to be able to 'inherit' the `--alignment` variable as it's a required input file for them all.

I tried adding `parents=[parser]` to each of the subparsers, but that seemed to break more things and I started getting:

`ArgumentError: argument -h/--help: conflicting option string(s): -h, --help`

Which I guess is the subparsers also inheriting the `-h` of the parent and causing issues?

## EDIT as per comments:

I moved the sub-parsers, but I still get an error that `-a|--alignment` is required, even when I invoke the command while specifying it.

```
def parseArgs():
    """Parse command line arguments. Includes parsing of subcommands."""

    import argparse

    try:
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='MSAnalysis',
                                         description="Perform simple tasks with multiple sequence alignments. \n The following subcommands are available:")
        subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(title='Subcommands')

        # Main parser required options
        parser.add_argument('-a',
                            '--alignment',
                            action='store',
                            required=True,
                            help='The multiple sequence alignment (MSA) in any of the formats supported by Biopython\'s AlignIO.')
        # Main parser options
        parser.add_argument('-f',
                            '--alnformat',
                            action='store',
                            default='fasta',
                            help='Specify the format of the input MSA to be passed in to AlignIO. [Default = fasta].')
        parser.add_argument('-v',
                            '--verbose',
                            action='count',
                            default=1,
                            help='Verbose behaviour, printing parameters of the script and status messages.')
        parser.add_argument('--makeplot',
                            action='store_true',
                            help='Plot the results via Matplotlib.')

        # parser_entropy
        parser_entropy   = subparsers.add_parser('entropy',
                                                 description='Perform calculation of the Shannon entropy per column of an MSA.',
                                                 help='Compute the Shannon entropy, per column of the MSA and return 2 vectors.')

        parser_entropy.add_argument('-m',
                                    '--runningmean',
                                    action='store',
                                    type=int,
                                    default=0,
                                    help='Return the running mean (a.k.a moving average) of the MSAs Shannon Entropy. Makes for slightly smoother plots. Providing the number of points to average over switches this on.')

        # parser_consensus
        parser_consensus = subparsers.add_parser('consensus',
                                                 description='Calculate a \'dumb\' consensus via BioPython.',
                                                 help='Computer a consensus sequence from the MSA, at a specifiable threshold.')
        parser_consensus.add_argument('-c',
                                      '--ambiguous',
                                      action='store',
                                      help='Specify what character default to use for ambiguous characters within alignments.')
        parser_consensus.add_argument('-t',
                                      '--threshold',
                                      action='store',
                                      help='Threshold cut off for the consensus sequence calculation.')

        # parser_dnds options
        parser_selection = subparsers.add_parser('selection',
                                                 description='Selection pressure Calculator',
                                                 help='Report dN/dS ratio in either a sliding window or for a whole sequence.')
        parser_selection.add_argument('-p',
                                      '--phylogeny',
                                      action='store',
                                      help='Specify a tree file computed from the supplied alignment for use with PAML.')

    except:
        print "An exception occurred with argument parsing. Check your provided options."
        traceback.print_exc()

    return parser.parse_args()
```

Additionally, moving the `subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(title='Subcommands')` line to *after* the options for the top-level (after the `--makeplot` argument) parser results in the same error.

Comment: I don't see why you need to add `--alignment` to the subparsers.  The value you provide to the main parser will be available regardless of which parser you use.

Comment: Usually when using `parents` you have to set `add_help=False` to either the parent or child, since by default a parser starts life with a `-h` argument (and a repeat definition is a conflict).  In general it's better to define a `parent` just for this inheritance role, and not plan on using it any stand-alone role.

Comment: I must be inadvertently asking an XY problem in that case. That is what I thought would happen, but when I run the code, say: `python MSAnalysis.py entropy -a ~/path/to/alignment` I keep getting the error that the argument is required, even though I've provided it.

Comment: Put those main parser arguments first, before the subparser command.  The main parser does all of its parsing, and passes the rest of the strings off to the subparser.

Comment: Ah great! It could be that simple? I'm not at my laptop now but will try that in the morning! Thanks

Comment: Tried following your advice @hpaulj however the same issue persists. I've edited my question with my current iteration of the code.

Comment: `python stack44812791.py -a test entropy -m 123` works with your latest code.  Resulting `args`: `Namespace(alignment='test', alnformat='fasta', makeplot=False, runningmean=123, verbose=1)`

Comment: Ah its expecting the positionals after, of course...This isn't ideally what I wanted however. I'd like to have the subcommand come first, followed by that compulsory argument applicable to each subcommand. I must be going about this the wrong way. I suppose it's not totally critical to what I'm doing though, so this works.

Comment: Check out my answer in this other recent  subparsers question:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44809222/argparse-mixing-parent-parser-with-subparsers